# No transfer of ether

Tags: solidity, addresses, struct, address.transfer, transfer

My Code below ( Following an Online Course, absolute beginner here ^_^)

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.17 <0.7.0;

contract CampaignFactory{
    Campaign[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public{
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(minimum,msg.sender);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);

    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns ( Campaign[] memory) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}


contract Campaign{

    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping( address => bool ) approvals;


    }


 Request[]  public requests;           
 address public manager;                     
 uint public minimumContribution;                      
 mapping( address => bool) public approvers;                       
 uint public contributersCount;                                         

    modifier restricted(){                       
        require(msg.sender == manager);                   
        _;                
    }                   

  // constructor************************************************  
    constructor(uint minimum,address creator) public {          
        manager = creator;
        minimumContribution = minimum;

    }


    function contribute() public payable{
        require(msg.value > minimumContribution);

        approvers[msg.sender] = true;
        contributersCount++;

    }



    function createRequest(string memory description, uint value, address recipient ) public restricted() {
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
            description: description,
            value: value,
            recipient: recipient,
            complete: false,
            approvalCount: 0

        });

        requests.push(newRequest);

    }

    function approveRequest( uint index) public{
        Request storage request_index = requests[index];

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);

        require(!request_index.approvals[msg.sender]);

        request_index.approvals[msg.sender] = true;

        request_index.approvalCount++;

    }

    function finalizeRequest(uint  index) public payable restricted {
        Request storage  request = requests[index];
        require(request.approvalCount > (contributersCount / 2));
        require(!request.complete);

        //address payable recipient = address(uint160(request.recipient));
        //recipient.transfer(request.value);
        // above is one of the ways i got to know for implementation but sticking to the course 
        payable(request.recipient).transfer(request.value);
        request.complete = true;

    }

}
```

NO ERROR but NO transfer of ether (last two lines), tried in REMIX everything works fine, except no  ether is transferred

A Beginner here, following an online course, making a DApp , also after compiling the contract through Compile.js, no build=> .json file is build, which i guess is because of faulty solidity contract above, works fine for the course instructor, i guess its because the code is outdated?

is there a solution for this or i have to find a alternative for this?

Comment: Works for me: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4c1e375ea5918076ffa4da0f2f9e4f4675ad04b2fea8af715646e38c1628ea0b. Maybe you are setting a `value` that is too high in `createRequest`? The contract can only send out ETH it previously received via `contribute`. On another note, please be aware that usage of `.transfer` is discouraged: https://diligence.consensys.net/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/.

Comment: so should i use below one instead ? :-                                                                                                     address payable recipient = address(uint160(request.recipient));
recipient.transfer(request.value);

Comment: That is the way that is described in the documentation at least: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/050-breaking-changes.html. 'Converting address to address payable is possible via conversion through uint160', but like I said the other way worked for me as well.

Comment: can you please paste the line of code for call.value() since it is displaying error regarding it is depricated and thank you for the help!

Comment: I have posted on your follow-up question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82412/using-value-is-deprecated-use-value-instead.