# Using ".value(...)" is deprecated. Use "{value: ...}" instead

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, address.transfer, transfer

This works fine in Remix but when trying to work in VSCode (for compiling purposes; DApp course, trying to build .json through compile.js ) it throws the error

1. > Using ".value(...)" is deprecated. Use "{value: ...}" instead.
2. > security/no-call-value: Consider using 'transfer' in place of 'call.value()'.
   >   from this line :-
   >   (bool success,) = recipient.call.value(request.value)("");    //Third last line below

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.16 <0.7.0;

contract CampaignFactory{
   Campaign[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public{
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(minimum,msg.sender);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);

    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns ( Campaign[] memory) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}


contract Campaign{

    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping( address => bool ) approvals;


    }


 Request[]  public requests;                   
 address public manager;                               
 uint public minimumContribution;                                 
 mapping( address => bool) public approvers;                     
 uint public contributersCount;                           

    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

  // constructor************************************************  
    constructor(uint minimum,address creator) public {
        manager = creator;
        minimumContribution = minimum;

    }


    function contribute() public payable{
        require(msg.value > minimumContribution);

        approvers[msg.sender] = true;
        contributersCount++;

    }



    function createRequest(string memory description, uint value, address recipient ) public restricted() {
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
            description: description,
            value: value,
            recipient: recipient,
            complete: false,
            approvalCount: 0

        });

        requests.push(newRequest);

    }

    function approveRequest( uint index) public{
        Request storage request_index = requests[index];

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);

        require(!request_index.approvals[msg.sender]);

        request_index.approvals[msg.sender] = true;

        request_index.approvalCount++;

    }

    function finalizeRequest(uint  index) public payable restricted {
        Request storage  request = requests[index];
        require(request.approvalCount > (contributersCount / 2));
        require(!request.complete);

        address payable recipient = address(uint160(request.recipient));
        (bool success,) = recipient.call.value(request.value)("");
        (success, "Transfer failed.");
        request.complete = true;

    }  

}
```

Comment: What version of solidity are you using? Perhaps you have one version configured in Remix and a different one in VSCode. I'd recommend to specify what version you want to use: `pragma solidity 0.5.16` (or use 0.6.5 if you want to target new version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an outdated error message. I assume you are using `ethlint` as linter which means you can silence this warning by creating a `.soliumrc.json` in your repository with the following content:

```
{
  "extends": "solium:recommended",
  "plugins": ["security"],
  "rules": {
    "no-call-value": "off"
  }
}
```

See the [Github issue](https://github.com/duaraghav8/Ethlint/issues/280) and further explanations on [how to use call.value](https://medium.com/@luizhamilton29/how-to-use-call-value-7b275ec7f568).

Comment: all went good ( gets compiled and i can build the .json files)and while i was running mocha test before deploying my contract ( DApp tutorial), i can clearly see that ether is not being transferred from the last function, the main issue related from the start to call.value()..................

Answer (score 18):

With respect to the `".value(...)" is deprecated. Use "{value: ...}"` warning:

You can use the following pattern to remove the warning:

```
(bool success, ) = recipient.call{value:amt}("");
require(success, "Transfer failed.");
```

---

[solidity.readthedocs.io , solidity dotsyntax   0.7.0 =>](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.2/using-the-compiler.html?highlight=%7Bvalue%3A%20...%7D#available-upgrade-modules)

> ```
> The following syntax is deprecated: 
> f.gas(...)(), f.value(...)() and (new C).value(...)().  
>
> Replace these calls by
> f{gas: ..., value: ...}() and (new C){value: ...}().
> ```