# how can i make external function call with value in solidity 0.5.6?

Tags: solidity

In solidity 0.6.x, this will work.

```
bentoBox.deposit{value: value}(token, msg.sender, to, uint256(amount), uint256(share));
```

I can call other contract's function with value.
How can I do this in solidity 0.5.6

When I compile, error comes out.
`ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{'`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `yourFunction.value(<wei>)(parameters)`.

This has been described here for example [Using ".value(...)" is deprecated. Use "{value: ...}" instead](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82412/using-value-is-deprecated-use-value-instead)

The easiest way to also check is to select a specific version in the Solidity docs (e.g. https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.6/control-structures.html?highlight=Value#creating-contracts-via-new)